# How to unite two datasets by a variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame A

```
a1 <- c(1,2,3,76,43,8,4,5,1)
a2 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2, 3 , 3, 3) #three individuals
A <- data.frame(a1,a2)
```

and a data frame B

```
b1 <- c(3,6)
b2 <- c(90,90)
b3 <- c(91,92)
B <- data.frame(b1,b2,b3)
```

and I want to create a new data.frame looking like

```
a1  a2
1   1   3   6
2   1   3   6
3   1   3   6
76  2   90  90
43  2   90  90
8   2   90  90
4   3   91  92
5   3   91  92
1   3   91  92
```

where b1, b2, b3 are added to the A dataset according to the three individuals in a2. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't find a common variable. Is it based on the rownames of 'B' and 'a2' column in 'A'?  May be `B1 <- t(B); cbind(A,B1[rep(1:nrow(B1),each=3),])`

Comment: or `cbind(A,do.call(rbind,rep(B,each=3)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C <- as.data.frame(t(B))
C$a2 <- seq_along(C$V1)
merge(A, C)
```

Result:

```
  a2 a1 V1 V2
1  1  1  3  6
2  1  2  3  6
3  1  3  3  6
4  2 76 90 90
5  2 43 90 90
6  2  8 90 90
7  3  4 91 92
8  3  5 91 92
9  3  1 91 92
```

Comment: The OP didn't mention about which is the common variable.  Anyway +1

Comment: sorry I wasnt specific about that, but the answer by @ulfelder gave me the situation I wanted.